# Where I can find edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep

Tags: java, nlp

I am trying to use Dependency Parser of Stanford's NLP in my project.
I am looking for `edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser.class` but cannot find any jar.

Where I can find. Should I have to run all CoreNLP to build jar?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the GitHub URL of CoreNLP https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP and documentation is available at http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/